# What happens to the new Python Tuple when it is added to itself

Tags: python

I have a beginner question on Python.  If I have a python tuple:

```
x = ('a', 'b', 'c')
```

and then `x + x` would give me:

```
('a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c')
```

#### Question:

What happens to the new Python Tuple when it is added to itself `x + x`?
I can reference the tuple `x` but what about the new tuple that is `x + x`, how would you reference?  Does it become a unreferenced memory, meaning no pointer can reference it?

Thank you,

G.

Comment: Just assign it to a new variable: `z = x + x`,  although I'm not entirely sure that's what you're asking.  The result of the addition *will* be lost if you don't assign it to something.

Comment: *how would you reference* - Store it into a variable or return it from a function...?

Comment: Derek, user3483203, I was read that when doing x + x, that becomes a new Tuple but cannot referenced because no variable is assigned to it.  But nosklo clarified for me.  The runtime takes care of the garbage collection.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

tuples are immutable. `tuple.__add__` (which is called when you add tuples) will return an entirely new tuple object with content of both tuples in it. To reference it later you have to store the reference in a variable:

```
new_tuple = x + x
print(new_tuple)
```

If you don't store the reference, it becomes "unreferenced" as you say in the question, and then the python garbage collector will destroy it and free the memory automatically. The same happens to any python object when the number of references to it reaches zero.

Comment: "then the python garbage collector will destroy it and free the memory automatically. "  

Thanks nosklo, that answered my question.

Comment: @Gerry you can mark the answer as **accepted** by clicking the green checkmark just under the voting buttons near the answer.